# Counting the negative values in vectors with random numbers

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I am trying to define a function counting the values that are less than 0 for two vectors
x=rnorm(100) and y=rnorm(500).

Define another function to calculate the
proportion that values are less than 0 for x and y respectively.

I will like to compare calculated
proportions with theoretical proportion 0.5.

```
myf <- function (x)
{
  a <- rnorm(100)
  b <- x[x < 0]
  return(a)
}

myf (x)
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Why do you return a and not b?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want, but this might help for your second part (as you want proportion) - `mean(rnorm(100) < 0)`

Comment: Hello @M-M, I am trying to trying to write a function which counts the values which are less than zero for to vectors x=rnorm(100) and y=rnorm(500).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
set.seed(92)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(500)

countnegatives <- function(a,b){

  counta <- sum(a<0); countb <- sum(b<0)

return(
  paste(deparse(substitute(a)), "has", counta, "negative numbers",
        "and",
        deparse(substitute(b)), "has", countb, "negative numbers")
)}

countnegatives(x,y)
#> [1] "x has 44 negative numbers and y has 267 negative numbers"
```

Or you can simply return `c(counta, countb)` in your function. If you want to get the proportions, you can divide `counta/length(a)` and the same for `b` and return that in your function.

Comment: @LAWONGDamian I added an explanation. Instead or `returning` all those text that I am `pasting` together, return, e.g., `counta/length(a)`. You can return two values by `concatenating` like this: `c(counta/length(a), countb/length(b)` . This is giving the proportion which for this random seed is 0.44 for `x` and ~`0.53` for `y`.